# MySQL data must exist in two columns to be returned

Tags: php, mysql

I'm stuck on the best way to achieve this MySQL query.

I have three tables:

**products** - this is a list of products

```
id | product_name
```

**cats** - this is a list of categories

```
id | category_name
```

**cats_selected** - multiple categories can be assigned to a product, this table lists them

```
cat_id | product_id
```

In a search a user can select multiple categories to search on at once. I want to check that a product exists in each category, so it needs to match cat_id and product_id. The cat id's are posted as an array.

What is the best way to query this data?

For example, the following doesn't work for obvious reasons:

```
SELECT *
FROM products
JOIN cats_selected
ON cats_selected.product_id = products.id
AND cats_selected.cat_id = '16372' 
AND cats_selected.cat_id = '9'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT p.id
FROM products p
JOIN cats_selected s ON s.product_id = p.id
where s.cat_id in (16372, 9)
group by p.id
having count(distinct s.cat_id) = 2
```

Comment: >=2 is probably better?

Comment: @allen213: It is not necessary since there are **exactly** 2 distinct `cat_id`s because of the  `where` clause.

Comment: Not sure I agree as he has said multiple rather than 2 in the question body, although the the sample data does of course have 2 items. I'm reading as at least two.

Comment: This has of course to be adjusted to the number of elements in the `in` clause. But for that example it is always `=2`.

Comment: I do not see why you are using the HAVING clause this would limit the users search to only ever searching 2 categories they would not get any results when searching for 1,3,8,19 categories

Comment: Yes this is what I was looking for, thanks juergen. I need the HAVING clause to limit the results returned. My example only showed two categories, but I would adjust according to the number of categories searched on. Thanks to everyone else for their help also.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work? Your query syntax is not right.

```
SELECT *
FROM products
JOIN cats_selected
ON cats_selected.product_id = products.id
WHERE cats_selected.cat_id IN ('16372', '9')
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your cat_id's array looks something like `[1,2,4,3,52]` you can use the IN function, and you need to have cats_selected.cat_id check in the WHERE part

```
$cat_ids = [1,2,4,3,52];
$catImplode = implode(",",$cat_ids);

$query = <<<END
   SELECT products.*, GROUP_CONCAT(cats_selected.cat_id) as cats
   FROM products
   JOIN cats_selected
   ON cats_selected.product_id = products.id
   WHERE cats_selected.cat_id IN ($catImplode)
   GROUP BY products.id
END;
```

This would end up with $query being:

```
SELECT products.*, GROUP_CONCAT(cats_selected.cat_id) as cats
FROM products
JOIN cats_selected
ON cats_selected.product_id = products.id
WHERE cats_selected.cat_id IN (1,2,4,3,52)
GROUP BY products.id
```

Added a GROUP_CONCAT column aliased to `cats` in case you need to know what categories where matched for the product